# Wrapping Spring Data JPA with ApsectJ

Tags: jpa, spring-data, aspectj, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

Is it possible?

Currently I am using some aspects for my `MVC` controllers, what works really fine. I'm wrapping their responses and I have desired effect.

I also want to do this with `Spring Data JPA` repositories. But since they're generated based on  the interface e.g:

```
public interface SomeRepository<T extends Some, ID extends Serializable> extends
    BaseRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    public List<T> findById(Long id)
}
```

It generates me controller which is ready to use:
    `http://localhost:8080/findById?id=1234`

I also want to wrap this controller. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAdvice {
  @Before("execution(* com.company.jpa.SomeRepository+.findById(..))")
  public void intercept() { ... }
}
```

Basically, we are telling the framework to intercept the call to the `findById` method on any sub-class of `SomeRepository`.

[Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-aop) is a sample application demonstrating this in action.

Comment: The thing is that this method `findById(Long id)`is generated by Spring data repository  (`@NoRepositoryBean`) and still, even with Your query I cannot hook on this method. 
Do you have any good and reliable source of `@AspectJ`

Comment: I'm not using this dependency

     `<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>`

But I'm still able to hook on other (non-repositories) methods.

Comment: You will need the AspecJ weaver for intercepting interface methods. The Spring AOP documentation has information on using AspectJ. However it takes a lot of experience and trial-and-error to get it working as expected in large applications. The Spring AOP documentation also suggests the use of AspectJ only in exceptional situations.  If you just use the code from my sample application you should be able to get things going quickly.

Comment: So there's absolute nessesity to use AspectJ weaver? I have some problems combining it with `Lombok` library in enterprise application.

Comment: You can either use runtime weaving, for which you will need the AspectJ weaver, or you can use compile-time weaving, for which you will need to run the AspectJ compiler on your compiled classes as part of your build-process.  The AspectJ advice will remain the same in both cases.  As far as Lombok (or any other library you may be using) is concerned, you can open a separate question with details on what problem you are facing using AspectJ with Lombok.  Someone may be able to help you with that.

Comment: Why do we need Intercepted annotation?

Comment: You can ignore that.  In an earlier version of the sample I had the `@Before` advice look for methods with that annotation.  Later, the sample worked without that annotation so I posted the simpler version in answer above.